# how to fill Stroke text in custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have prepared one custom view that view code is,

```
    mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            mPaint.setTextSize(100);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

          canvas.drawText("Android",100,100,mPaint);


    }
```

result view is,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDXL3.png

here i want fill with some color inside "Android". I have prepared one more paint object that is,

```
mAlphaInner.setDither(true);
        mAlphaInner.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
        mAlphaInner.setTextSize(98);
```

added in onDraw(),

```
 canvas.drawText("Android",100,100,mPaint);
```

but view is ,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHueB.png

please help me how to fill with color inside "Android".

Comment: Did you checked below answer with FILL_AND_STROKE ?? What is the result ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you would try `mPaint.setStyle(Pain.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE)`

**EDITED:**

Forget about `Paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER)` in both paints

Comment: if i try mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE) fill with white color ,but i want filll with different color.

Comment: You are using white color. mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF); check it

Comment: after added this line in two paints view is like this, http://i.imgur.com/zt9gL.png

Answer (score -1):

Draw your text twice, using two different modes.

```
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mPaint.setTextSize(100);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        mAlphaInner.set(mPaint);  //Set the same text size!
        mAlphaInner.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
        mAlphaInner.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawText("Android",100,100,mAlphaInner);
      canvas.drawText("Android",100,100,mPaint);
   }
```